# Regex Replace Without String Redeclaration

Tags: c#

I'm currently doing a bunch of Regex replaces like this

```
_skeleton = Regex.Replace(_skeleton, "&%currTIME", DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

Is there any way to make it so I don't have to write '_skeleton ='?

Maybe using 'out'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since strings are immutable, you cannot change their contents. You must create a new string with the contents you want.

Think of it like any other immutable type (DateTime, int, etc.)

```
int i = 1;
i++; // i = i + 1
i += 2; // i = i + 2

DateTime d = DateTime.Now
d = d.AddDays(1);

string s = "s";
s = s + "tring";
```

You can wrap the functionality to be a little more functional in nature:

```
public void MyRegexReplace(ref string mystring, string pattern, string replaceWith)
{
    mystring = Regex.Replace(mystring, pattern, replaceWith);
}
```

And then call it like:

```
MyRegexReplace(ref _skeleton, "&%currTIME", DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

But this doesn't seem that useful to me.

Comment: Just use `mystring` as a ref parameter :/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have to keep repeating yourself for multiple replacements on the same string, you can nest the calls to `Regex.Replace()`:

```
_skeleton = Regex.Replace(
                    Regex.Replace(_skeleton, "foo", "bar"),
            "&%currTIME", DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

---

(Editing the answer because my response is too long for a comment)

You don't need to even indent them:

```
_skeleton = Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace/*...*/(_skeleton,
            "foo", "bar"),
            "baz", "blaz"),
            //..
            "TIMTOWTDI", "There Is More Than One Way To Do It"
            ));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have like 20 replaces. It's unreadable without writing a new line.

Comment: @cam: I've put a response to your comment in my original answer, because the comment box is too awkward for it.

Answer (score 0):

How about defining:

```
 void static void RexReplace(ref strTarget, string searchPatter, string replacePattern)
 {
      str = Regex.Replace(str, searchPatter, replacePattern); 
 }
```

And then write

```
 RexReplace(ref _skeleton, "&%currTIME", DateTime.Now.ToString());
```